# apt install package that depends on other package, but alternate is installed

Tags: apt, deb

I am trying to install `subuser`, but it depends on `docker.io`.

```
subuser : Depends: docker.io but it is not going to be installed
```

However I have `docker-ce` installed.

I created a deb package using `equiv-control`

```
Section: local
Priority: optional
Package: my-docker-dependencies
Version: 1.0
Maintainer: ctrl-alt-delor
Depends:  docker-ce
Provides: docker.io
Description: docker
```

But I get a conflict

`Breaks existing package 'docker-ce' that conflict: 'docker.io'. But the 'my-docker-dependencies_1.0_all.deb' provides it via: 'docker.io'` (`docker-ce` is already installed).

This conflict makes sense, but I don't know how to fix things so that I can install `subuser`.

How can I install `subuser` with `docker-ce`, but not `docker.io`?

Comment: It might be simpler to rebuild that package after editing the dependencies.

Comment: Wouldn't be it easier just to uninstall docker-ce and install docker.io?

Comment: @Biswapriyo I am considering it, but there is a major version difference, so may be some loss of functionality.

Answer (score 2):

`docker-ce` itself conflicts with `docker.io`, so I don’t think there’s a way to make this work by adding another package which provides `docker.io`.

I suspect the only way to install `subuser` with `docker-ce` is to rebuild `subuser` with an alternative dependency:

```
Depends: ${misc:Depends}, ${sphinxdoc:Depends}, ${python3:Depends}, python3-pkg-resources, git, docker.io | docker-ce
```

The full recipe would be

```
apt source subuser
cd subuser-*
sed -i 's/Depends:.*/& | docker-ce/' debian/control
dch -n "Allow docker-ce instead of docker.io."
dch -r ignored
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

Comment: Your 1st paragraph what what I figured out (I was just being optimistic and looking for a workaround) I will give your way a try. Unfortunately I have suddenly got a bigger problem: My main system won't boot (https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/534873/4778). Also will you solution prevent `subuser` from receiving upgrades?

Comment: This won’t prevent upgrades, no. But `subuser` will only be upgraded if the new version has satisfiable dependencies.