# Convert GPT (UEFI / secure boot), to MBR / BIOS

Tags: boot, partition-table

I have just installed Debian 10 (Buster). I have come to the conclusion that UEFI does not work on my device (despite it being in the firmware setup). For some reason, the install has converted the old MBR/DOS partition table into GPT. And now it dose not boot.

**I would like to ether convert it back. Or keep GPT, but convert boot loader to use old method**, maybe using protective MBR https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Hybrid_MBR_(LBA_0_+_GPT) . I have tried to re-install `grub` using the installer rescue mode, but this fails ( see [new Debian install will not boot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/534873/4778) if you want more detail on this ).

So how do I make it bootable using MBR, without reinstalling whole OS (and /home)?

---

I am booted into gparted live.

`fdisk -l /dev/sda` shows

- Partition table type (Disklabel type): gpt
- root partition type: EFI System
- 4 blocks free at end of disk (for 2nd copy of gpt)

`fdisk -t mbr -l /dev/sda` shows

- The whole disk reserved for GPT (protective MBR)

Comment: If you're currently in GPT but using BIOS, you have to create an extra bios_grub partition(might need to be the first partition) because GPT doesn't allow enough space to embed the grub stage 1.5. Then use nornal grub-install as in normal BIOS mode. Or find someway to convert GPT back to MBR, but if you have more than 4 partition under GPT, it would be hard, since partition header already occupied by filesystem so can't support EBR. In that case, you'll have to move the whole filesystem. Not impossible, but very tedious.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you think that your device's UEFI firmware will not boot Debian 10?   What is the make/model of your device?

Comment: It is a lenovo yoga 3 11. When I tell it to boot the installer USB via UEFI, it does boot, but then I can't get it to work (can't remember the errors). When I ask it to boot the main disk via UEFI, it shows a white flashing underscore in the top left of a black screen.

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 I have 1M “Un-used” at start of disk (a few blocks for the gpt, then I don't know what), is it possible to use this space. How can I find out what it is?

Comment: I never met such situation myself. But GPT partition table structure SHOULD be at the start of the disk(backup GPT is at the end of disk, not related), why would you see free space at the start of disk, too weird, did you mean a few logic sectors not occupied by any partition after the GPT? If yes, why not try use `parted` to add a partition to occupy those space as grub_bios? But notice GPT is not a fixed length structure, hope your current Partition Entry Array still has some free space to add a new entry

Comment: I don't think Hybrid GPT is a good idea. Does grub support that? Does Linux support that? Personally, I suggest people just backup their /home then reinstall. And further, people might want a more stable, more maintainable GPT+bios_grub+ESP+large brtfs/Logical Volume Group solution. So to avoid problem like, "Oh, no, now I want add a new partition, but the first partition already started, I don't have enough space in the disk header area to add a new partition entry".

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 I have been reading and have gone off the idea of hybrid. I thought that I could but grub 1st stage in the (protective MBR), and it would find the 2nd stage in the first gpt partition. Now I am thinking that I convert the partition table. If there are no tools, I could record the partition begin/end, and create the new table, but will it boot, is there any thing in the OS that is expecting GPT. Or do I just then re-install grub?

Comment: To switch GRUB from UEFI to MBR, you'll need to uninstall the packages `grub-efi-amd64`, `grub-efi-amd64-bin` and possibly `grub-efi-amd64-signed` (= Secure Boot support), and install `grub-pc` and `grub-pc-bin` instead. Only after that you can reinstall GRUB in its MBR-compatible form. If you're still booted in UEFI style when installing MBR-style GRUB, you may need need to specify the target platform type explicitly: `grub-install --target=i386-pc ...`

Comment: @telcoM I have now discovered the grub packages that you say I need to have installed are the ones installed. There are no grub-efi installed. So this can not be the cause. I have experimented with doing the opposite, this also did not work. I think I need to convert the partition table, or fix EFI.

Comment: No, I don't think something in the OS would expect GPT. If you decide to convert GPT to MBR, make sure you don't have more than 4 partition, or you might run into "no space for EBR" problem. If you wanna keep GPT, you might want to find out why you have free space in the header instead of right after the GPT. The original can't-boot-problem might be caused by such a broken partition table. bios_grub is for stage1.5, stage 2 can be on almost abirotory filesystem. https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/BIOS-installation.html

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 What is this word abirotory?

Comment: https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/tablets/yoga-series/yoga-tablet-2-1050/documentation may be helpful

Comment: "arbitrary", spelling error. When you install grub, you specify a boot-directory, then grub-install will install proper module into stage1.5 so it will have ability to read from stage2, which is bunch of files in the filesystem

Comment: (arbitrary that makes sense now) I am wondering why grub-pc (the one that is installed), can not work with gpt. Can not stage 2 be in `/boot` of the root partition of a gpt. Also where is stage 1.5 kept?

Comment: Archlinux only have one package of grub. Did you mean "BIOS version of grub"? It can work with GPT or MBR. But stage 1 is too small, so it needs stage 1.5 out of filesystem. By such, grub gains full ability of reading filesystem (or say, enoughly powerful stage2). Don't know what's "root partition of a gpt", all partitions are equal in GPT scheme. Stage 1.5 is usually right after partition table, it's not filesystem.

Comment: For MBR, grub-install expect you have enough gap between fixed-512-byte MBR and first partition. For GPT, grub-install expect you have one partition of type 21686148-6449-6e6f-744e656564454649. Both are for stage1.5. Stage 1+1.5 together, gain the ability of reading partition table and reading filesystem. I believe LBA addressing is used and hard-coded by stage1 to find stage1.5 during the runtime

Comment: Notice grub2 can be directly installed into a btrfs. I never read the source code of grub, but I believe such case is btrfs filesystem data structure has enough space in the the header to keep stage 1+1.5(but still use hard-coded LBA addressing), then stage 2 is simply a directory on this btrfs.